# Do I HAVE TO unsubscribe from all events in all cases?

Tags: c#, uwp

For example, if I have a UserControl or a Page that creates its own event in its code-behind file, when that Page or control unloads, do I have to make sure its events are unsubscribed from? I mean there are no external subscriptions. Every subscriber is self-contained, so I would THINK that it wouldn't matter once the control is unloaded:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.Unloaded += Page_Unloaded;
        this.Tapped += Page_Tapped;
    }

    private void Page_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some work here.
    }

    private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Is the following appropriate and REQUIRED?

        this.Unloaded -= Page_Unloaded;
        this.Tapped -= Page_Tapped;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to unsubscribe. You are not creating any additional references to `MyPage`. When each request is complete and each instance of `MyPage` goes out of scope there are no references to the instance that need to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

No, under normal circumstances - unloading is not required.

However, if you create your own static delegates, then you must remember to unload them - as they are not removed when your instance goes out of scope.